# Expose interface to pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am trying to expose a interface (aka a class with no implementation) to Python using pybind11

I am not sure if pybind11 was built to this, because everything that I saw in their documentation is about to generate modules for python usage, and not to embedded.

I tried this:

```
py::object main = py::module::import("__main__");
py::object global = main.attr("__dict__");

py::class_<Person>(global, "Person", py::module_local()).def("say", &Person::say); # Crashes when I added this line

py::exec(R"(
class Rodrigo(Person):
    def say(self):
        print("Hello world from Python!")

rodrigo = Rodrigo()
rodrigo.say()
)");
```

But it crashes, the back trace says something in GIL.

Is it possible to do what I am trying?

Comment: Did you read the pybind11 docs about [trampoline classes](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/classes.html) ? Also, your example is not complete, missing `Person` definition, full error message, includes.

Comment: You are right, but the documentation never mentioned PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with

```
PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE(carimbo, m) {
  py::class_<Person, PyPerson, std::shared_ptr<Person>>(m, "Person")
      .def(py::init<>())
      .def("say", &Person::say);

  py::class_<World>(m, "World")
      .def(py::init<>())
      .def("add", &World::add)
      .def("all", &World::all);
}
```